# <a href="javascript:void(0);" download>download</a> stop downloading

Tags: html

my problem is when `<a>` tag has no link so how to stop download when click on link

**for example:my link is below**

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" download>download</a>
```

so when i click on below link download a `void(0)` file

but i want to stop downloading when `<a>` tag ha no link and `href=javascript:void(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i have solve problem with `<?php condition`

if variable have no value than create `<a>` tag with  no `download` option and if variable have value create `<a>` tag with download

Answer (score 1):

just remove download attr from your tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="classname">download</a>
```

or you can use jquery

```
$('tag.classname').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //this stop default prevent or action
  or you can use 
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```js
$('a.demo').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //this stop default prevent or action
      //or you can use 
      e.stopPropagation();
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="demo" download>download</a>
```

or with javascript

```js
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="demo" download>download</a>
```

Comment: when `href=""` have any `pdf` file or `image` how to download without `download` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Write a **click** event handler and prevent the default events like below,

```
$('a#id-of-it').on('click', function(event) {
  // Do whatever you want
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

And the html looks like,

```
<a href="#" id="id-of-it">Download</a>
```

Comment: but without jquery or javascript

Comment: You can add onclick attribute and just return statement like onclick="return false;"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a.demo').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //this stop default prevent or action
      //or you can use 
      e.stopPropagation();
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="demo" download>download</a>
```